# Android HAS_PHONE_NUMBER

Tags: java, android, contacts, contactscontract

I am trying to write a method that determines if a contact has at least one phone number, at the moment I have this:

```
public boolean hasPhone() {
 Cursor phones = this.map.getContentResolver().query(
  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
  null,
  ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "=" + this.contactId,
  null,
  null
 );
 boolean has = false;
 if(phones.moveToFirst()) {
  do {        
    if(Integer.parseInt(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
      has = true;
      break;
    }
  } while(phones.moveToNext());
 }
 return has;
}
```

the method always returns false, even though I know the contact in question has a phone number.  Also I know the contactId is correct as I also use it to get the postal address, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am about to tear my hair out :p

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest to use the debugger to evaluate where is the bug.  Does phones.moveToFirst return true? What about phones.getColumnIndex?

Comment: Hi Guido, thanks for the reply.

No moveToFirst does not return true. Does this mean the contact does not exist with that id?

Comment: According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst(\)), it returns false if the cursor is empty. So, your `query(...)` isn't returning any rows.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks, it is strange though, as I have a very similar method that returns the contacts name which works fine

Comment: I decided to output all the phone numbers to the log with there CONTACT_ID, and none of the CONTACT_ID's match those of the actual contacts on the phone.

I am really unsure why this is, as I can fetch the contacts addresses with this id.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Replace the following line

```
ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "=" + this.contactId,
```

with this line

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + this.contactId,
```

See if that works.